# Touch Id Not working when I used react-native-touch-id below is my code when i click toggleTouchId() it retun me error isSupported is not defined

Tags: android, ios, react-native

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import { View, ScrollView, Text, Switch,Alert, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
    import { connect } from 'react-redux'
    import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation'
    import PinInput from 'react-native-pin-input';
    import { VALER_PURPLE, VALER_BACKGROUND, VALER_LABELTEXT, VALER_CELLBORDER } from '../../Assets/GlobalStyle'
    import { ButtonCell } from '../Templates/ButtonCell'
    import TouchIDScan from 'react-native-touch-id'; **strong text**
    class TouchIDPIN extends Component {
        static navigationOptions = {
            title: 'Touch ID & PIN',
            headerStyle: { backgroundColor: VALER_PURPLE },
            headerTintColor: 'white',
            headerTitleStyle: { alignSelf: 'center' },
            headerRight: (<View></View>)
        };

        state = {
            PIN: false,
            touchID: false,
        }
        componentWillMount() {
            if (this.props.navigation.state.params && this.props.navigation.state.params.radioEnable) {
                this.setState({ PIN: this.props.navigation.state.params.radioEnable });
            }
            else {
                this.setState({ PIN: this.props.user && this.props.user.enabledPin ? this.props.user.enabledPin : false })
            }
        }
        changePin = () => {
            if (this.state.PIN) {
                this.props.navigation.navigate('ChangePin');
            } else {
                alert("Please Enable Pin first");
            }
        }
        togglePin = () => {
            if (this.props.user && this.props.user.enabledPin == false) {
                this.setState({ PIN: false });
                this.props.navigation.navigate('ChangePin');

            }
            else {
                this.setState({ PIN: !this.state.PIN });
            }
        }
        _pressHandler() {
            // alert("")
            TouchIDScan.authenticate('to demo this react-native component')
                .then(success => {
                    Alert.alert('Authenticated Successfully');
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log('Authentication Failed',error);
                });
        }
        toggleTouchId() {
            TouchIDScan.isSupported().then((res) => {
             console.log('TouchID is supported.');

            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log('TouchID is not supported.',err.message);
            })


        }
        componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
            this.setState({ PIN: nextProps.user && nextProps.user.enabledPin ? nextProps.user.enabledPin : false })
        }
        render() {
            return (
                <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: VALER_BACKGROUND }}>
                    <Text style={{ color: VALER_LABELTEXT, marginTop: 10, paddingLeft: 10, fontSize: 13 }}>Security Options</Text>
                    <View style={{ height: 1, backgroundColor: VALER_CELLBORDER }} />
                    <View style={{ marginTop: 3, paddingLeft: 10, height: 90, backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
                        <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                            <Text style={{ flex: 1, fontSize: 17 }}>PIN</Text>
                            <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'flex-end', paddingRight: 10 }}>
                                <Switch
                                    value={this.state.PIN}
                                    onValueChange={() => this.togglePin()}
                                // disabled={true}
                                />
                            </View>
                        </View>
                        <View style={{ height: 1, backgroundColor: VALER_CELLBORDER }} />
                        <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                            <Text style={{ flex: 1, fontSize: 17 }}>Touch ID</Text>
                            <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'flex-end', paddingRight: 10 }}>
                                <Switch
                                    value={this.state.touchID}
                                    onValueChange={this.toggleTouchId.bind(this)}
                                />
                            </View>
                        </View>
                        <View style={{ height: 1, backgroundColor: VALER_CELLBORDER }} />
                    </View>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={{ marginTop: 20 }} onPress={() => this.changePin()}>
                        <ButtonCell
                            section='2'
                            key='2'
                            Label="Change PIN"
                            Style={{ color: 'blue' }}
                        />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <View style={{ marginBottom: 30 }} />
                </ScrollView>
            )
        }
    }
    const mapStateToProps = ({ state, action, auth }) => {
        return {
            state,
            action,
            user: auth.user
        }
    }
    export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(TouchIDPIN);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `import TouchID from 'react-native-touch-id'` on top of the `js` file.

Comment: Same error  

TouchID is not supported. Cannot read property 'isSupported' of undefined